# how to hide image without break layout with css

Tags: html, css

I have Implemented this design with custom CSS, On the Image. I have to show four categories of details. I have implemented the programming, But I am facing Issues In aligning them vertically.

I have applied a display none for the picture, but the layout gets suspended when asked, and when I had done image opacity to 0% image height persists.

[Here Is my code:](https://jsfiddle.net/q41o7dvs/)

```css
.main-box{
        padding: 1rem;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    min-width: 130px;
    max-width: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 150px;
   max-height: 150px;
    }
    .main-box img{
        width: 30%;
        border-radius:50%;
        display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }
    .main-box p,a{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .main-box a{
        display: block;
    }
    .show{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .main-box:hover img{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .main-box:hover .show{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .main-box:hover {
        background:url(https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-box">
        <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"/>
        <div class="show-info">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>batch</p>
    </div>
        <div class="show">
            <p>join</p>
            <a href="#">profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you're asking - try changing the `.show` CSS to set `display: none`.

The `opacity` property will only change *how much* visibility the element has when rendered - but its "footprint" on the page will remain.

If you instead use `display: none;` CSS, the element's "footprint" in the DOM will be ignored.

See below:

```
.show {
  display: none;
}
```

You also want to include a wrapper `<div>` around the `.main-box` elements so you can set the behavior for the collection of boxes. I just added a `<div class="main">` with the following CSS behavior:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

For grid situations you would benefit from taking a flexbox-based approach - see the [W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for more info - good luck!

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.main-box {
  margin: .5rem .5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.main-box img {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.main-box p,
a {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-box a {
  display: block;
}

.show {
  opacity: 0;
}

.main-box:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.main-box:hover .show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main-box:hover {
  background: url(https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff" />
    <div class="show-info">
      <p>name</p>
      <p>batch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <p>join</p>
      <a href="#">profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Flexbox is very powerful - definitely worth investing some time to get the basics integrated into your workflow - once you know enough to apply it in your HTML there's no going back :)